# what double question mark on rxjava-string means?

Tags: java, rx-java, inputstream

I came up with this piece of code for emitting every pieces of text file with a delimiter, but the frist emitted string have a double question mark at the beginning,

**I really have no idea where is this double question mark come from**

for instance this is my text file contents

**test.txt**

`pieceOne;pieceTwo;pieceThree;`

and this is my output with `;` delimiter in the console:

```
??pieceOne    
pieceTwo    
pieceThree
```

and here is my code:

```
public Observable<String> readFile(String filePath, String delimiter) {
        return Observable.just(filePath)
                .map(Paths::get)
                .map(this::safeInitializeInputStream)//just initialize inputstream here
                .flatMap(in -> readInputStream(in, delimiter))
                .observeOn(scheduler);
    }

private Observable<String> readInputStream(InputStream is, String delimiter) {
        return StringObservable
                .split(StringObservable.from(new InputStreamReader(is,
                        Charset.forName("UTF-8"))), delimiter);
    }
```

any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: Most probably the file is from a Windows machine, was saved by notepad.exe as UTF-16, and the first two characters are "byte order mark", aka BOM. They must be `0xff` `0xfe` normally. Check in a hex viewer.

Comment: @9000 yeah damn right,thanks plz post ur comment as an answer so that I can accept you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from a comment)

Most probably the file is from a Windows machine, was saved by notepad.exe as UTF-16, and the first two characters are "byte order mark", aka BOM. They must be `0xff` `0xfe` normally. Check in a hex viewer.

These bytes can be safely omitted if the rest of the data are ASCII. If not, you have to properly decode from UTF-16; the decoder will take care of the BOM.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find your used class 'StringObservable'. I instead used

> ```
> compile "com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.17.0"
> ```

I think ?? is because of two bytes which can not be represented with UTF-8.

```
@Test
void name() {
    // pieceOne;pieceTwo;pieceThree;
    readFile("/home/sergej/Desktop/wurstdatei", ";")
            .test()
            .assertValues("pieceOne", "pieceTwo", "pieceThree");
}

private Observable<String> readFile(String filePath, String delimiter) {
    return Observable.just(filePath)
            .map(Paths::get)
            .map(path -> Files.newInputStream(path))
            .flatMap(in -> readInputStream(in, delimiter))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io());
}

private Observable<String> readInputStream(InputStream is, String delimiter) {
    return Flowable.just(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)))
            .scan("", (s, bufferedReader) -> bufferedReader.readLine())
            .compose(StringFlowable.split(delimiter))
            .toObservable();
}
```